# PHP MySQL Tables Assistance

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, statistics

I have a script which I edited a little bit, on a page, it doesn't show the 7 day stats, what could cause this?

Here is a partial code of the page
(By the way I tried restoring backup, and no changes at all so it must be from somewhere else)

```
echo("</td><td>");
@mysql_free_result($res);
$i = 0;
$res = @mysql_query("select date from 7stat where usrid=$usrid order by date desc limit $keep_stats");
$darr = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < @mysql_num_rows($res); $i++) {
    $darr[] = @mysql_result($res, $i);
}
$mvcx = $keep_stats-1;
@mysql_free_result($res);
$i = 0;
if (mysql_query("select count(*) from 7stat where usrid=$usrid") > $keep_stats) {
    @mysql_query("delete from 7stat where usrid=$usrid && date < $darr[$mvcx]");
}
$darr2 = array();
reset($darr);
while (list($k, $v) = each($darr)) {
    $res = @mysql_query("select num from 7stat where date='$v' && usrid=$usrid");
    $darr2[$v] = @mysql_result($res, 0);
    @mysql_free_result($res);
}
$maxnum = 0;
reset($darr2);
while (list($k, $v) = each($darr2)) {
    $maxnum = $maxnum + $v;
}
$maxnum = round($maxnum);
echo("\n<b>Surf Credits Earned Last $keep_stats Days:</b><br><table border=0 cellpadding=2>");
reset($darr2);
while (list($k, $v) = each($darr2)) {
    $v = round($v, 2);
    $px = 500 * ((($v * 100) / $maxnum) / 100);
    $px = round($px);
    echo("\n<tr><td style=\"background-color: #4DA0C6\"><font color=\"#FFFFFF\"><b>&nbsp; $k &nbsp;</b></font></td><td align=left> - <b>$v credits</b></td></tr>");
}
echo("</table>");
echo("</td></tr></table>");
```

Comment: Removing all those error suppressors is a start.

Comment: OK, if it's not showing the stats, what is happening? are you getting an errors output to the browser?

Comment: The main problem probably is that prepending `@` to functions prevents any kind of error output, thus you have no chance of catching any problems with the database connection. As a first step, remove all the `@`s and instead add something like this to the functions: `mysql_query(...) or die('MySQL error: '.mysql_error());`

Comment: Also guys instead of saying last 7 days it says "Surf Hits Received Last 0 Days: and Surf Credits Earned Last 0 Days:"

Comment: I am really new to php i really need some good explanations

Answer (score 1):

Your `"Surf Hits Received Last 0 Days: and Surf Credits Earned Last 0 Days:"` line is build with the help of the `$keep_stats` variable. If the value of this variable is `0`, as evidenced in the previous string, your SQL query will include the line `LIMIT 0`, which will suppress MySQL from returning any rows.

Your solution lies in finding out where `$keep_stats` is set and why it's set to `0`.

I'm also not sure what

```
 if (mysql_query("select count(*) from 7stat where usrid=$usrid") > $keep_stats)
```

is supposed to mean. `mysql_query` will return a `Resource`, which you'll have to parse with `mysql_result` or another such function to use.